# How can I extend the constructor of an AngularJS resource ($resource)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-factory

I have a model, defined using `$resource`, that I am successfully loading.

Each loaded instance is, as promised, an instance of the class I defined.

(The example below is from the Angular docs. In it, `User.get` results in an object that is an `instanceof User`.)

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
```

However, imagine each User comes over the wire like this:

```
{
  "username": "Bob",
  "preferences": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "foo",
      "value": false
    }
  ] 
}
```

I defined a `Preference` factory that adds valuable methods to `Preference` objects. But when a User loads, those `preferences` aren’t `Preference`s, naturally.

I attempted this:

```
User.prototype.constructor = function(obj) {
  _.extend(this, obj);
  this.items = _.map(this.preferences, function(pref) {
    return new Preference(pref);
  });
  console.log('Our constructor ran'); // never logs anything
}
```

But it has no effect and never logs anything.

How can I make each item in my `User`s’ `preferences` array an instance of `Preference`?

Comment: Do I need to load things outside of Angular and then create a `new User` myself for each loaded user, after taking care of `preferences`?

Comment: I think that you can use a response interceptor in your resource, and modify the response as per your needings. If interested I have a code that achieve something similar.

Answer (score 12):

$resource is a simple implementation, and lacks in things like this.

`User.prototype.constructor` won't do anything; angular doesn't try to act like it's object oriented, unlike other libraries. It's just javascript.

..But luckily, you have promises and javascript :-).  Here's a way you could do it:

```
function wrapPreferences(user) {
  user.preferences = _.map(user.preferences, function(p) {
    return new Preference(p);
  });
  return user;
}

var get = User.get;
User.get = function() {
  return get.apply(User, arguments).$then(wrapPreferences);
};
var $get = User.prototype.$get;
User.prototype.$get = function() {
  return $get.apply(this, arguments).$then(wrapPreferences);
};
```

You could abstract this into a method which decorates any of a resource's methods: It takes an object, an array of method names, and a decorator function.

```
function decorateResource(Resource, methodNames, decorator) {
  _.forEach(methodNames, function(methodName) {
    var method = Resource[methodName];
    Resource[methodName] = function() {
      return method.apply(Resource, arguments).$then(decorator);
    };
    var $method = Resource.prototype[methodName];
    Resource.prototype[methodName] = function() {
      return $method.apply(this, arguments).$then(decorator);
    };
  });
}
decorateResource(User, ['get', 'query'], wrapPreferences);
```

Comment: I think where you have `var methodName` in the function at the bottom, you probably meant `var method` and then in the next line `Resource[methodName]` instead.

Comment: Good explanation. Probably there's a mistype in parameters order between `decorateResource` declaration and its invocation.

Comment: Looking again at 1st block of code, shouldn't it be: `var $get = User.prototype.get;` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by overriding the built-in resource actions to transform the request and response (See [transformRequest and transformResponse in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).):

```
var m = angular.module('my-app.resources');
m.factory('User', [
          '$resource',
  function($resource) {

    function transformUserFromServer(user) {
      // Pass Preference directly to map since, in your example, it takes a JSON preference as an argument
      user.preferences = _.map(user.preferences, Preference);
      return user;
    }

    function transformUserForServer(user) {
      // Make a copy so that you don't make your existing object invalid
      // E.g., changes here may invalidate your model for its form, 
      //  resulting in flashes of error messages while the request is 
      //  running and before you transfer to a new page
      var copy = angular.copy(user);
      copy.preferences = _.map(user.preferences, function(pref) {
        // This may be unnecessary in your case, if your Preference model is acceptable in JSON format for your server
        return {
          id: pref.id,
          title: pref.title,
          value: pref.value
        };
      });

      return copy;
    }

    function transformUsersFromServer(users) {
      return _.map(users, transformUserFromServer);
    }

    return $resource('/user/:userId', {
        userId: '@id'
      }, {
        get: {
          method: 'GET',
          transformRequest: [
            angular.fromJson,
            transformUserFromServer
          ]
        },
        query: {
          method: 'GET',
          isArray: true,
          transformRequest: [
            angular.fromJson,
            transformUsersFromServer
          ]
        },
        save: {
          method: 'POST',
          // This may be unnecessary in your case, if your Preference model is acceptable in JSON format for your server
          transformRequest: [
            transformUserForServer,
            angular.toJson
          ],
          // But you'll probably still want to transform the response
          transformResponse: [
            angular.fromJson,
            transformUserFromServer
          ]
        },
        // update is not a built-in $resource method, but we use it so that our URLs are more RESTful
        update: {
          method: 'PUT',
          // Same comments above apply in the update case.
          transformRequest: [
            transformUserForServer,
            angular.toJson
          ],
          transformResponse: [
            angular.fromJson,
            transformUserFromServer
          ]
        }
      }
    );
  };
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem as yours. I came up with the following approach.
This example is based on Offers instead of Users, as domain entity. Also, please note here's a trimmed down version of the whole thing, which in my case spans over some files:

Domain entity custom class:

```
function Offer(resource) {
    // Class constructor function
    // ...
}

angular.extend(Offer.prototype, {
    // ...

    _init: function (resource) {
        this._initAsEmpty();

        if (typeof resource == 'undefined') {
            // no resource passed, leave empty
        }
        else {
            // resource passed, copy offer from that
            this.copyFromResource(resource);
        }
    },

    copyFromResource: function (resource) {
        angular.extend(this, resource);
        // possibly some more logic to copy deep references
    },

    // ...
});
```

Classic angular custom resource:

```
var offerResource = $resource(/* .. */);
```

Custom repository, passed to controller by a service factory:

```
function OfferRepository() {  
    // ...
}

angular.extend(OfferRepository.prototype, {
    // ...

    getById: function (offerId, success, error) {

        var asyncResource = offerResource.get({
            offerId: offerId

        }, function (resource) {
            asyncOffer.copyFromResource(resource);

            (success || angular.noop)(asyncOffer);

        }, function (response) {
            (error || angular.noop)(response);

        });

        var asyncOffer = new offerModels.Offer(asyncResource);

        return asyncOffer;
    },

    // ...
});
```

Most noticeable parts are:

- the custom entity class, that is able to construct/fill itself starting from a resource instance (possibly with deep copy capabilities, e.g. Positions in an Offer)
- the custom repository class, which wraps the resource. That does not returns the classic async resource answer, but instead returns an custom entity instance, and later on it fills that with the resource just loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to modify the constructor property of the prototype object won't do what you expect anyhow, please take a look at the very nice post [here](http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/).

To really understand what is going on, one should look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js) of the `ngResource` module - there are a lot of things at work there, but what's important is that the `$resource` factory returns a plain JavaScript function (really, what else). Invoking this function with the documented parameters returns a `Resource` constructor object, which is defined privately in `resourceFactory`.

As you may recall, AngularJS services are singletons, meaning that calling `$resource` will return the same function every time (in this case, `resourceFactory`). The important takeaway is that every time this function is evaluated, a new `Resource` constructor object is returned, meaning that you can prototype your own functions on it safely, without worrying that this will pollute all `Resource` instances globally.

Here is a service that you can use much as the original `$resource` factory, while defining your own custom methods that will be available on all of its instances:

```js
angular.module('app').factory('ExtendedResourceFactory', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {                                                        
    function ExtendedResourceFactory() {
      var Resource = $resource.apply(this, arguments);

      Resource.prototype.myCustomFunction = function() {
        ...
      };

      return Resource;
    }

    return ExtendedResourceFactory;
  }
]);
```

Inside `myCustomFunction` you have access to the data returned from the server so you can use `this.preferences` and return whichever custom class you want to build.

Comment: this didn't work for me or I missed something. I added a new question that is very related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921494/how-can-i-get-the-url-from-an-ng-resource

Answer (score 1):

`transformResponse` does the job. Consider example (I wanted to use Autolinker to format response content).

```
return $resource('posts/:postId', {
    postId: '@_id'
}, {
    get : {
        transformResponse : function(data) {
            var response = angular.fromJson( data );
            response.content = Autolinker.link(response.content);
            return response;
        }
    },
    update: {
        method: 'PUT'
} });
```