# AngularJS: automatically chaining $resource actions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I've got an AngularJS resource implementation, which (in principle) works fine. Now the special circumstances are:

- one of the fields (attributes) of the resource is the "last changed timestamp"
- if it arrives at the server in an updating request, it is ignored. The sever sets the "last changed timestamp" always automatically
- the updating methods on the server are all implemented in a way, that the response is empty (rather than containing the modified entity)

So under these circumstances, to get the "last changed timestamp" after an update operation from the server, I always have to do a get immediately following the update.

```
myEntity.$update( function(){ myEntity.$get(); } );
```

**Now the question is:** Does AngularJS offer a way to automatically chain actions:

- to define in the MyEntity definition, that it needs to always do a $get after the $update.
- and then, in application code just call

  ```
  myEntitty.$update();
  ```

Comment: Have you considered adding your own methods to myEntity? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076309/where-to-place-resource-specific-logic

Comment: Thanks! not sure, why I didnt think about that myself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @marck for pushing me in the right direction. The solution is basically

```
    var MyEntity = $resource( ...,
        { 
            get: {...},
            update: {...}
        }
    );


    // params is passed to $update.
    // after successful $update, a parameterless $get is called
    // success is called after successful $get
    // error is called if $update OR $get failed
    // returns the promise of the $update
    MyEntity.prototype.$updateAndRefresh = function(params, success, error){
        var item = this;
        return item.$update(params, function(){
            item.$get(success, error);
        },
        error);
    }
```